# Django - Preview uploaded picture prior to deciding to save

Tags: django

Like the title suggested, I want to implement a two-steps picture uploading mechanism.

1. User selects a picture to upload and
   click on "Upload". Once the server
   receives the request that contains
   the picture, it would save the
   picture in a temporary location, on
   disk or memory, and the resize it to
   a standard size, if needed. The
   server then renders a new response
   for the user to preview the uploaded
   picture.
2. After previewing the picture, the user needs to click on "Save" to confirm for the server. The server then moves the picture from the temporary location to a permanent one and updates the corresponding entry in the DB.

What's a good way to implement this? What are some of the apps out there that might be able to help me? Thanks.

Comment: I have decided to try out django-image-cropper [Link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-image-cropper/0.1), which looks quite straight forward while being easy to use. I'll come back with my experience with the app.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either rolling your own (you might find it surprisingly easy, start with reading the [docs on forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs)) or customizing [django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/) or [django-filebrowser](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/).